# Permission set for a user

Tags: profile, permission-sets

I'm new to Salesforce, and had a question about Profiles and permission sets

Suppose I have a user Bob with the following profile :

***Standard User*** :

*Can create and edit most major types of records, run reports, and view the org's setup. Can view, but not manage, campaigns. Can create, but not review, solutions. Can edit personal quota and override forecasts.*
([Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_permissionset_licenses_and_perm_sets.htm&type=0))

Bob can create accounts, contacts and opportunities and whatever.

I have edited this Profile so that it can't access a custom field on the *Account* object called *Language*.

Knowing that there are several people with this profile, I just want Bob to access this field.

I created a permission set. In *Object Settings*, under *Accounts*, I selected both **Read Access** & **Edit access** for the *Language* field and assigned the permission to Bob.

Is it enough for Bob to access the field ?

The reason I'm asking the question, is that I can still see rows with *No access* (on permission set page) and wondering if permission sets can restrict some permissions the user had with his profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, Yes a Permission Set will provide access to the specific fields for Bob and whoever else is assigned this Permission Set. They are an additive rather than restricting access.

Permission sets extend users’ functional access without changing their profiles.

The number of Permission Sets a User may have will be dependant on the Salesforce edition.